# Completely disabling mouse support in QEMU

Tags: x11, mouse, qemu

I'm currently using QEMU for some work involving the VGA console.

I'd like to turn off click-to-grab, which constantly triggers when I press CTRL+ALT+DEL (which my host Linux system is configured to ignore).

I'd also like to avoid using autograbbing as enabled by `-usbdevice tablet`, since that makes it impossible to alt-drag the QEMU window.

I don't mind leaving the emulated PS/2 mouse on (since it's not annoying me); I simply want QEMU to ignore my real mouse cursor.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You might try using a vnc console instead, `-display vnc=:11` and `vncviewer :11`.

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion in theory, however a) QEMU's VNC server occasionally sends confusing packets on screen change, causing clients to disconnect, and b) I'm actually doing things with tight timing requirements, and the VNC server is likely to drop frames, which won't work for me.

Comment: After reading [`sdl.c`](http://git.qemu.org/?p=qemu.git;a=blob_plain;f=ui/sdl.c;hb=HEAD) I can see that this functionality is currently completely unimplemented.